# How to fix androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to com.rey.material.widget.Button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, runtime-error

I'm building a amazon like app. after coding the loginactivity I can't access it from mainactivity because it always crashes

this is my loginactivity.java

```
public class loginActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private EditText InputPhoneNumber, InputPassword;
    private Button LoginButtonPage;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

    private String parentDbname = "Users";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        LoginButtonPage = findViewById(R.id.page_login_btn);
        InputPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.login_phone_number_input);
        InputPassword = findViewById(R.id.login_password_input);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);


        LoginButtonPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                LoginUser();
            }
        });

    }

    private void LoginUser()
    {
        String phone =InputPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
        String password =InputPassword.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please Write Your Phone Number...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please Write Your Password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            loadingBar.setTitle("Login Account");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please Wait, while we are checking the credentials.");
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            loadingBar.show();

            AllowAccessToAccount(phone, password);
        }
    }

    private void AllowAccessToAccount(final String phone, final String password)
    {
        final DatabaseReference RootRef;
        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(parentDbname).child(phone).exists())
                {
                    Users usersData = dataSnapshot.child(parentDbname).child(phone).getValue(Users.class);

                    assert usersData != null;
                    if (usersData.getPhone().equals(phone))
                    {
                        if (usersData.getPassword().equals(password))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "logged in successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(loginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            Prevalent.currentOnlineUser = usersData;
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
                else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Account with this" + phone + "number do not exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "you need to create a new account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is my loginactivity layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    tools:context=".loginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login_applogo"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/applogo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_phone_number_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_applogo"
        android:background="@drawable/input_design"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_password_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_phone_number_input"
        android:background="@drawable/input_design"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_password_input"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/remember_me_checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Material.Drawable.CheckBox"
            android:text="Remember Me"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:cbd_strokeColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/forget_password_link"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Forgot Password?"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/page_login_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/loginbutton"
        android:padding="17dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/admin_panel_link"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I'm an Admin"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/page_login_btn"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/not_admin_panel_link"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I'm an not Admin"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/page_login_btn"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

then I get this error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.infinite.fastfood, PID: 12305
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.infinite.fastfood/com.infinite.fastfood.loginActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to
>   com.rey.material.widget.Button
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to
>   com.rey.material.widget.Button
>           at com.infinite.fastfood.loginActivity.onCreate(loginActivity.java:36)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Comment: It looks like the `Button` you've imported in `loginActivity` is `com.rey.material.widget.Button`, but that `<Button>` in your layout is going to end up being an `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton`. Depending on what you actually want, either change the import to `import android.widget.Button;`, or change the XML tag to `<com.rey.material.widget.Button>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing com.rey.material.widget.Button import to androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Users" instead of parentDbName.
 if (dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(phone).exists())

Answer (score 0):

In firebase, you are creating account for admin, change in firebase from phone: 9999999999 to phone: "9999999999". means add double quote(") in name,phone and password.

if you are not puting double quote in firebase the data is in long datatype. But the java file want all data in string value.