# how to resolve mistakes androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be thrown to android.widget.ImageView on the AlertDialog that I made

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I tried to make AlertDialog but I got a crash error problem, I tried a number of ways but it still didn't work, from changing the constrainlayout to LinearLayout by adding Id but this method still works

*xml*

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/parent_view"
android:padding="20dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Cencel payment"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black_000000"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Confirm if you are sure to cancel this payment."
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnContonuewPayment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_payment_orange_ff8830"
            android:text="Continue Payment"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white_FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_back_to_home"
            android:text="Yes, Cancel"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FF8830"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnContonuewPayment"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnContonuewPayment"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnContonuewPayment" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I tried this method [how to fix androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to com.rey.material.widget.Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264088/how-to-fix-androidx-appcompat-widget-appcompatbutton-cannot-be-cast-to-com-rey-m) by adding id and changing it to Linearlayout but it still crashes

*kotlin*

```
private fun showDialog() {

    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    val viewDialogForget = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_payment,null)
    val continuew = viewDialogForget.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.btnContonuewPayment)
    val cancel = viewDialogForget.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.btnCancel)
    dialogBuilder.setView(viewDialogForget)
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
    val dialog = dialogBuilder.create()
    dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))


    continuew.setOnClickListener {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    cancel.setOnClickListener {
        finish()
    }

    dialog.show()
}
```

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: I create an imageView with the id on the toolbar, when I press the back arrow it should display an alert dialog that I have included in the xml code and the box, but it crashes @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: Alert dialog in XML? Do you want to have an alert dialog in onbackpressed function?

Comment: I have an activity which has a back icon on the toolbar when I press the back arrow on the toolbar it will display AlertDialog @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: the title above and I'll show the picture @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: Attach your activity code please

Comment: i don't if it is what in kotlin what i think it is but val cancel = viewDialogForget.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.btnCancel) are you trying to covert a button in an ImageView

Comment: this is icon arrow  -> https://ibb.co/NNv92YW this is crash https://ibb.co/NNv92YWhttps://ibb.co/60BCq5k

Comment: Don't put your back button in image view

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin code icon arrow -> btnBackVirtualAccount.setOnClickListener {
   showDialog()
  }

Comment: This layout that I click on the back arrow icon on will display a dialog, which I have implemented displays an error crash  https://ibb.co/nzZczrR

Comment: Why don't you attach your full code?

Comment: this is code -> https://pastebin.com/ZMtuacmd @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: why are you binding textviews to imageviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display like pop up ...follow below code and make necessary design in xml as per ur requirement.

```
 class Testing: AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.testing)


    imageButton.setOnClickListener {

        setupAlertDialog()
    }

}

private fun setupAlertDialog() {

var dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

   var inflater = this.layoutInflater

    var message:View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_dialog,null)

    dialog.setView(message)
    dialog.show()

}
```

}

use inflater to pur your xml file the one you mentioned initially

Comment: this works for me even though there is a avoid avoid null warning as the root view in this null code

inflater.inflate (R.layout.dialog_payment, null)

The following code that I implemented -> https://pastebin.com/sTKTZZk7

Answer (score 0):

No need to create additional buttons in xml for alert dialog it can be done smoothly by coding. Here is an example of it.

```
private fun setupAlertDialogButton() {
    alertDialogButton.setOnClickListener {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
            .setTitle("Discard draft?")
            .setMessage("Your message.")
            .setPositiveButton("Discard") { dialog, which ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked discard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, which ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            .show()
    }
}
```

alertDialogButton should be your backbutton ID

Comment: if I want custom alertDialog what, because I've made it custome @Srikanth G

Comment: that depends on your requirement how u want to display the message, the above code is just about normal display like yes or no option

Comment: if u have idea about how ur dialog should pop up can help in coding

Comment: what if I want to make a button in the middle with a vertical orientation like my design -> https://ibb.co/FhTZT78 @Srikanth G